# Rights required to generate EF model for DB2 tables

Tags: entity-framework, db2, mainframe, rights

We are trying to use EF 4.1 to access DB2 tables.

We have installed DB2 Connect 9.7 fix pack 4.

We get to the point where we can select tables. All tables are shown. To test we select 2 of the tables.

What happens then is the it hangs, with the timer going round and round and round ...

The user that is setup to access the tables has read/write access.

Anyone know if we need more rights to generate the EF model, or anything else that could be causing this problem?

**Edit**

It has finally given an error message:

> ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  Det er
>   oppdaget en kommunikasjonsfeil.
>   Kommunikasjonsprotokoll som brukes:
>   "TCP/IP".  Kommunikasjons-API som
>   brukes: "SOCKETS".  Stedet der feilen
>   ble oppdaget: "172.20.170.39". 
>   Kommunikasjonsfunksjon som oppdaget
>   feilen: "recv".  Protokollspesifikk(e)
>   feilkode(r): "10053", "*", "*". 
>   SQLSTATE=08001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a communications error -- your application isn't able to reach the database.

Please check that you have the correct IP address for the database server and the correct port number.

If these are both correct, make sure that any firewalls between your client and the database server are not preventing the connection, or routing issues, etc.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that we were trying to pull over too much data. It works when we filter a single view, then add one view at a time to the model.